How to simplify this DEV script for faster running Express with GraphQL with Prisma
"dev": "export NODE_ENV='development' && DEBUG=*,-babel-watch:*,-babel,-babel:*,-express:*,-nodemon,-prisma:*,-prisma:client:*,-body-parser:json,-nodemon:*,-babel-watch:*,-winston:*,-ioredis:*,-nodemon::*,-snapdragon:*,-prisma-client,-finalhandler,-winston:create-logger,-follow-redirects nodemon --exec babel-watch index.js",

This script is using by the previous developer , How to simplify this ,so that it will take less time to start the project.Actually currently it is taking 20 mins to start while running pnpm run dev.And one more thing is I found in some places that this DEBUG makes slow the process but I can not remove that as the developer has used this debug statement in hundreds of places ,so its almost impossible to manually remove all these lines.So please help me to fix this.Debug lines are used like this,
import Debug from 'debug/src/node' // Npm: debugging library.
Debug('Category -> Finding Category Details')(`Name: ${name} `)

Thanks in advance....

thanks for your question. It seems that the commands being used “-snapdragon” is skipping “snapdragon” related debug prints. On our end, we set up a local environment and created a hello world app. This took us a short amount of time (less than 10 minutes), with or without the debug prints that are skipped. It seems that this issue may be specific to the app you are using.
